# ADO/ASP/MVC - ошибки с ключами в таблицах

Tags: asp.net, c#, mvc, ado.net, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день.

Создаю веб-приложение ASP MVC.
Для доступа к базе данных использую модель ADO EDM. Создал подключение.Теперь создаю контроллер:
[image]

clients - таблица в базе

Получаю ошибку:

[image]

Пишет, что вроде как во всех мои трех таблицах нет ключей. Атрибуты я ставил ([Key] перед ID-шным полем), все равно.

Может я делаю чего не так, подскажите! Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Добрый день!

Дело в том, что EntityFramework по умолчанию, как первичный ключ ище поле id, однако, если вы используете любое другое поле в качестве первичного ключа (Primary key), вам необходимо использовать ключевое слово: **[Key]**

```
    public partial class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int CatId { get; set; }
        public string CatName { get; set; }
        public string CatDescription { get; set; }
        public List<Product> Product { get; set; }
    }
```

Если же после этого у вас все равно возникает ошибка, велика вероятность того, что вы используете вторичные ключи без соответствующего объявления.

Вторичные ключи задаются ключевой функцией  **ForeignKey("App_user")**, для примера:

```
public partial class User_role
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("App_user"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    [Key, ForeignKey("Role"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int role_id { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual App_user App_user { get; set; }
}
```

Так же, обращу ваше внимание на то, что в References проекта должна быть подключена библиотека EntityFramework.dll и на то, что cj вторичными ключами в .Net 4.0 будут некоторые проблемы, которых не будет в .Net 4.5

Тем не менее вы можете работать со вторичными ключами в .Net 4.0 путем связующих LINQ SQL запросов (JOIN, UNION и.т.д).

С уважением!

Comment: использую Framework 4.5.
Сделал как вы предлагаете, ошибки все те же остались. Добавил пустую таблицу, с одним ключом (отдельную АДО модель сделал), так при создании контроллера "Нет доступных классов модели". А тут что не так ? одна таблица, 1 перв. ключ, поле Id присутствует...

Comment: Ошибки остались 100% все старые? Т.е. для ново созданной таблицы не прибавилось ошибок?

Comment: Да, ошибки тебе.  Аналогичные ошибки даже при добавлении новой таблицы, которая ни с чем не связана.

Comment: А для новой таблицы в вашем списке появились ошибки? Т.е. вы создали таблицу допустим users, появились ли для нее ошибки?